# ruby inbuilt function not working in a .rb file

Tags: ruby

I am unsure why my ruby code is not working, and any advice or help would be appreciated.

Could someone kindly advise me on how I can make this code work:

```
result = fetch_value.join(',').split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

I have the file below, named codeit.rb

```
# Function definitions first
def menu
  # Clear the screen, and present the user with a menu
  puts `clear`
  puts "***Flatten an Array***"
  puts "would you like to flatten an array?"
  print "(y)yes, (n)no, (q)quit: "
  gets.chomp.downcase
end

def flatten_array
  print "great! lets do this! "

  result = fetch_value.join(',').split(',').map(&:to_i)

  puts "the answer is #{result}"
  puts "press return to return to menu"
  gets
end #end of flatten_array method

def fetch_value
    puts "Please enter an array: "
    gets.chomp
end



# run the app...
response = menu 
while response != 'q'
  case response
  when 'y'
    flatten_array
  when 'n'
    advanced_calc
  end
  response = menu
end
```

Running this code in the terminal, I get the following:

```
***Flatten an Array***
would you like to flatten an array?
(y)yes, (n)no, (q)quit: y
great! lets do this! Please enter an array: 
[[1, 2, [3]], 4]
codeit.rb:14:in `flatten_array': undefined method `join' for "[[1, 2, [3]], 4]":String (NoMethodError)
    from codeit.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

But when run similar commands in irb, the code seems to work:

```
2.3.0 :082 > array
 => [[1, 2, [3]], 4] 
2.3.0 :083 > 
2.3.0 :084 >   
2.3.0 :085 >   
2.3.0 :086 >   array.join(',').split(',').map(&:to_i)
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.3.0 :087 >
```

Comment: Don't do things like `puts \`clear\``, instead call `system('clear')` if you *must*. If you want to make an interactive interface use the [curses library](https://github.com/ruby/curses).

Comment: `join` takes an array and turns it into a string. Here you already have a string. You need to re-evaluate your strategy

Comment: `.join().split()` is not the same thing as `.split().join()`...

Comment: _ruby code is not working_ is not clear. What do you expect your code to do? What happens instead? Is there an error message? What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetch_value` method returns a string, not an array. And as the error says, the String class doesn't have a `join` method.

If you'd like to treat the string as an array -- essentially evaluating it as ruby code -- you could always use `eval`. Be aware that in any real code it's rather dangerous to use eval on a user-entered string, since your code will happily run whatever the user gives it.

With that caveat, you could do this:

```
def fetch_value
  puts "Please enter an array: "
  eval(gets.chomp)
end
```

You'll probably also need to consider what to do with the array. Currently, you're combining its elements into a string and then splitting that string back into an array, which doesn't make a lot of sense. And since your example also uses nested arrays, that join-and-split tango probably isn't doing what you think it is.